# Using 'Class'-type object to create an object it's representing

Tags: java, class, generics, types

Let's say I have an object created from class:

```java
public Class Cat {
  public Cat(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

```java
Cat cat = new Cat("Just cat");
```

I create a Class-instance of my cat like this:

```java
Class catClass = cat.getClass();
```

My question is, can I use that Class-object to create cats by doing something like this:

```java
Cat newCat = catClass...something...("Another cat");
```

My problem is that I have a method accepting array of strings. This method needs to decide which object it has to construct using these strings as arguments. I tried to use getConstructor methods, but I can't seem to figure out how this works.

Comment: Voting to re-open because the linked question assumes you are working from a String class name. OP asked if you could create a new instance from an object, which doesn't require you to get the class name. This would work: cat.getClass().getConstructor( String.class ).newInstance( "Another cat" )

Comment: @JesseBarnum It shouldn't matter how you get the `Class` instance. The OP here already has one. The linked post explains how you can then use it to instantiate the class.